# How to Properly Use a Direction Switch in a Doubly Linked List?

Tags: c, big-o, doubly-linked-list

I have a doubly linked list and I want to change the direction of the list. For instance:

1 -> 2 -> 3

becomes

3 -> 2 -> 1

I have used a boolean expression in my structure to determine the direction.

```
typedef struct Node Node;

struct Node {
char character;
Node *link[2];
bool dir;
} direction;
```

I determine the direction with this format:

```
Node *p;
p->link[p->dir];
```

or

```
Node *p;
p->link[!p->dir];
```

The issue that I'm having is I want to flip these boolean directions with a method that uses a runtime of O(1). I have attempted to build a function that handles it like this:

```
//global variable
int d = 0;

//function
void switchStack ( ) {
    if (d == 0) {
        d = 1;
        direction->link[direction->dir] = direction->link[!direction->dir];
    else if (d == 1) {
        d = 0;
        direction->link[direction->dir] = direction->link[!direction->dir];
    }
```

This function doesn't seem to do anything and any other variation I try crashes the program when I call it. Does anybody have any idea on how to use the direction switch properly to reverse the stack with a runtime of 0(1)?

Comment: Why do you want to put `dir` in the node _itself_? With a DLink list, you can pass `dir` as an argument to all traversal functions and don't need to flip it in _each_ node [which just seems wasteful and not necessary]? What are you really trying to do? If you wanted to pass around lists that are "self describing", I'd create a list struct (e.g.) `typedef struct list { Node *head; Node *tail; int dir; } List` and put the direction flag there

Comment: @CraigEstey I am trying to create a function that will completely flip the order of the linked list, or flip the stack. I want to find a way with one function to cause the stack to flip with a runtime of O(1). What do you mean by "you don't need to flip each node"?

Comment: Your code flips with O(n). With a list struct, you simple do `list->dir = ! list->dir` to get O(1). It seems that you don't actually want to change the link pointers??? Just whether you traverse forward (e.g. `head` to `tail`) or backward (e.g. `tail` to `head`)?

Comment: @CraigEstey I do want to change what the link pointers represent. For instance, I want true to become false and vice versa when the function is employed.

Comment: By _represent_, I assume you want to change the _meaning_: (e.g.) If dir==0, link[0]===next and link[1]===prev. And, If dir==1, link[0]===prev and link[1]===next. **But**, you do _not_ want to physically interchange the contents of link[0] and link[1] as in: `Node *tmp = link[0]; link[0] = link[1]; link[1] = tmp;`?

Comment: @CraigEstey I apologize if I'm explaining poorly. The second scenario you gave is what I wish to do. I want to literally flip the contents of the stack so top becomes head and head becomes top.

Comment: You can not do that in O(1). You can use the flag to choose the direction of traversal (head to tail or tail to head) and that choice is O(1), but the traversal itself will remain O(n). And simply messing about with your list anchor node (where head and tail are stored) would leave your list in a borken state (head and tail would be reversed but the new head;s next would still point to the anchor as would the new tail's prev).

Comment: But honestly I have a hard time seeing a circumstance with a doubly-linked list where any re-ordering of the nodes is actually necessary when all you want to do is choose the order of traversal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is prefaced by my/the top comments.

I'm still not sure exactly what you want. But, this is as close as I can divine/guess.

The `listadd` *always* appends to the *tail* of the list (i.e. it *ignores* `dir`).

But, `listprint` honors the `dir`. It is a model for other functions you may write.

But, I think only `listprint` needs to look at `dir`. All other functions can treat a given list as a forward list (i.e. see how `listadd` works).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node Node;
struct node {
    Node *links[2];
    int value;
};
#define PREV    0
#define NEXT    1

typedef struct {
    Node *begend[2];
    int dir;
} List;
#define HEAD    0
#define TAIL    1

static inline Node *
listfirst(List *list)
{
    return list->begend[list->dir ? TAIL : HEAD];
}

static inline Node *
listlast(List *list)
{
    return list->begend[list->dir ? HEAD : TAIL];
}

static inline Node *
nodenext(List *list,Node *cur)
{
    return cur->links[list->dir ? PREV : NEXT];
}

static inline Node *
nodeprev(List *list,Node *cur)
{
    return cur->links[list->dir ? NEXT : PREV];
}

List *
listnew(void)
{
    List *list = calloc(1,sizeof(List));

    return list;
}

Node *
nodenew(int value)
{
    Node *cur = calloc(1,sizeof(Node));

    cur->value = value;

    return cur;
}

void
listadd(List *list,int value)
{
    Node *node = nodenew(value);
    Node *prev = list->begend[TAIL];

    do {
        if (prev != NULL) {
            prev->links[NEXT] = node;
            node->links[PREV] = prev;
            break;
        }

        list->begend[HEAD] = node;
    } while (0);

    list->begend[TAIL] = node;
}

void
listprint(List *list)
{
    Node *cur;

    for (cur = listfirst(list);  cur != NULL;  cur = nodenext(list,cur))
        printf("%d\n",cur->value);
}

int
main(void)
{
    List *list = listnew();

    listadd(list,1);
    listadd(list,2);
    listadd(list,3);

    printf("\n");
    printf("list in forward direction\n");
    listprint(list);

    // reverse the list
    list->dir = ! list->dir;

    printf("\n");
    printf("list in reverse direction\n");
    listprint(list);

    return 0;
}
```

---

This is the output of the program:

```
list in forward direction
1
2
3

list in reverse direction
3
2
1
```

Comment: If that's not what you wanted, I think you'll have to really think about what you need, and you can modify what I've posted, or rewrite your existing code.